# SSRS 2005 - Get average age of all Males/Females at company

Tags: reporting-services

I have to be dangerously close to getting this, but my expression still returns #Error.

I need to return the average age of all employees in my dataset who have a Gender of "F"/"M"

I've tried all manner of revisions of the following, but to no avail.

```
=IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", Avg(Fields!Age.Value,"ReportDataset"),Nothing)
```

Then, of course I'll do the same thing with "M"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I got this...

```
=Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "M", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset")
```

Now, just need to convert to an int to get rid of the 8-9 decimal points.

Comment: You got it. Just use the tables number format to show no decimals.

Comment: What glh said. Use formatting to simply hide the accuracy instead of throwing it away with rounding.